Passing from global number field to local number field
I want to clarify my understanding of the localization of the global field.
Let $K$ be a number field, that is a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb{F}_p(x)$. These are not complete fields. Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of integers of $K$ and $P$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$. We can define some $P$-adic topology on $\mathcal{O}_K$ with the basis set of the form $x+P^n$, $x \in \mathcal{O}_K,~n \in \mathbb N$. Now, we can complete $\mathcal{O}_K$ with respect to the $P$-adic topology to obtain a completed ring $\mathcal{O}_{K,P}$ such that the prime ideal $P$ completes to a unique maximal ideal in $\mathcal{O}_{K,P}$. Hence, we can consider the residue field $\kappa_P:=\mathcal{O}_{K,P}/P$, while the field of fraction of $\mathcal{O}_{K,P}$ is the localized field $K_P$ at $P$. For each prime ideal $P$ of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, one gets similarly a localized field $K_P$.
Is my understanding reasonable?
Ofcourse, one can consider the absolute value $v$ corresponding to each prime ideal $P$ of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ and obtain a completed ring $\mathcal{O}_{K,v}$, a local ring and hence a local field.

@user297024, Thank you for pointing out my silly mistake. Yes the corresponding local field is the field of fraction of $\mathcal{O}_{K,P}$
